# How can I set an entrybox in the middle and filling the titlebar between buttons

Tags: c, webkit, gtk3

I wanted to make an easy web browser. For that I need the entrybox to be in the middle of my header bar and filling the holse space up.

The entry box is in the middle of the bar but not filling the space between the buttons.

```
gtk_header_bar_set_custom_title(GTK_HEADER(w->header), w->entry);
```

The problem is I have two buttons on the left and 3 buttons on the right. The entrybox is in the middle of the hole bar but not filling the spce between the buttons. I also don't know if there is another function for this or if I used the wrong funktion.

Comment: `gtk_widget_set_hexpand`,  `gtk_widget_set_halign` on w->entry

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev Thanks that worked

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev Please make your comment into an answer, and Unknown please accept it. Thanks for providing great questions and answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, however, may not work on older GTK+-3 versions due to this bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=724332

But still try this out:
gtk_widget_set_hexpand(w->entry, TRUE);